# I am creating a python program that filters text. How do I have the program search the computers files instead of manually dragging the file to python

Tags: python, replit

[image: Where I have to drag the file before the filter.]This is my existing code:

```
input = open("first file.txt", "rt")
output = open("revised.txt", "wt")
for line in input:
  output.write(line.replace("Bob", "James").replace("Xavier", "Jake"))
input.close()
output.close()
```

Now, this works but I have to manually add "first file.txt" to python and the program doesn't search the computers files. How would I make the program automatically search the computers files? Attached is a photo of where I have to drag in case your confused.

Answer (score 3):

You're not "adding files to Python". You're adding them to REPL.it's website, which have their own file-system, and is where the code reads the files from.

Since you are using an online web interface, there is no possible way to make it search your *local* computer's files.

If this is what you want, install Python and run your code locally.

Comment: If I want to send this program to someone will they have to have python installed?

Comment: Not required. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-can-i-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependen